# MsalClientException the calling app is not supported by broker

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal

Hello all I implemented this lib in my project :

[microsoft-authentication-library-for-android](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android)

This works fine except in a few devices where it crashes on the initialization part :

```
    PublicClientApplication.createMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication(activity.getBaseContext(),
                R.raw.msal_config,
                new IPublicClientApplication.IMultipleAccountApplicationCreatedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreated(IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication application) {
*** not reaching
}

                    @Override
                    public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                        //Log Exception Here
                        showAlert(exception.toString()); //<- error

                    }
                });
```

and prints the exception :

> MsalClientException: The calling app is not supported by the broker

Anyone who can shed some light on this issue ?

Comment: Is Chrome installed on devices where you are getting this exception? MSAL uses chrome for  authorization requests.

Comment: @murgank yes it is

Answer (score 0):

**MsalClientException: The calling app is not supported by the broker**
The error states that you need to install broker app like authenticator.

so one of the two solutions can fix your issue

1. update the Company portal Intune app.
2. Install authenticator or corresponding broker app

Comment: can you elaborate on 1. ? we user Appcenter not intune , and what is authenticator ?